# Should I save auth-token in my Database at server side while creating mobile app

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, authentication, jwt

I am very new to backend and started creating an application with NodeJS and Express using Postgres but I am concerned about should I store **auth-token** in database itself? If not where should I store it as user will be logged in into the mobile application like forever.

Thank you :)

Comment: No need to store token in DB. On Mobile, you should save it in local/cache storage and pass it in headers whenever you hit the API. On NodeJs side, JWT will handle the token and verify token method will give the user token object.

Comment: @ChandraShekar suppose user kills the app and server connection to that application is closed, in that case will JWT be able to handle same auth-token for the next time whenever user creates or makes an API call ?

Comment: Yes it get handled and if you have that previous auth token to pass on to API. Make sure JWT has a token expiry time. If the token time got expired, you will get invalid token response from JWT.

Comment: I don't think the token should get expired suppose I start my mobile application after 10-15 days then in that case my token will be sent from mobile application, but JWT will be able to handle the same, even if I don't want to put expiry on token

Comment: Yes it will get handled.

Comment: Okay great let me try once.